# What are the preconditions for cutting hands of a thief?

Tags: fiqh, punishment, theft

If someone is found to be guilty of theft, there applies 
Islamic law concerning theft; that is, the hand should be cut off from the wrist joint.

> “[As for] the thief, the male and the female, amputate their hands in
>   recompense for what they earned [i.e. committed] as a deterrent
>   [punishment] from Allah. And Allah is Exalted in Might and Wise.”
>   [Quran 5:38]

Now my questions are,

- Does this apply to all cases of theft, or are there certain preconditions?
- Which are the countries where this law is applicable?
- Is there any record of how many people got this punishment? (country wise where this rule applies)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to different Hadith from [Imam Sadiq a.s.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ja%27far_al-Sadiq) and other Ahl ul bayt there are 19 preconditions for amputating hand of a thief.  If any of these preconditions are not met the hand should not be cut but still the thief has other punishments. Also, [the cut of hand should be from end of fingers and the palm of hand should remain.](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/4113/from-where-the-hand-of-the-thief-should-be-amputated)

According to [The Twenty-Third Greater Sin: Stealing](http://www.al-islam.org/greater-sins-volume-2-ayatullah-sayyid-abd-al-husayn-dastghayb-shirazi/twenty-third-greater-sin):

> 1. The thief must be an adult.  Abdullah Ibn Sinan relates the following tradition from Imam Ja’far as-Sadiq (a.s.):
>
>    > When a minor child steals for the first and the second time he is
>    >     forgiven. If he does it for the third time he is issued a strict
>    >     warning and beating. If he persists in his crime, the tips of his
>    >     fingers are slightly cut and if he repeats the act, some more of his
>    >     fingers are cut away.
> 2. The thief must be sane. So if an insane person robs, his hand is not amputed. He may be suitably warned and scolded.
> 3. The thief must not have resorted to stealing under duress, if he had been compelled to do so, the penal code is not applied.
> 4. The stolen thing must be something that is worth owning. Hence, if ones freedom is restricted it cannot be called a theft.
> 5. The value of the stolen object must not be less than one-fourth misqal of pure gold. One misqal is equal to eighteen grams. One-fourth
>      misqal is four-and-a-half gram.
> 6. The son or the slave of the thief must not own the thing that is stolen. So if a father steals from his son, he is not punished.
> 7. Eatables stolen during the times of famine do not make the thief liable for having his hands cut. It is narrated from Imam Ja’far
>      as-Sadiq (a.s.) that he said:
>
>    > In the time of famine and draught the hands of a thief are not cut off
>    >     for stealing edible items like bread and meat etc.
> 8. If a soldier participates in a raid and steals from the plundered goods obtained in war before they are distributed, he is exempted from
>      the punishment.
> 9. If one of the parties to a transaction steals a property and claims that it rightfully belongs to him, he is not liable to be punished.
> 10. If a person is accused of theft, but before his theft is proved to the judge, he pays the owner the value of the goods, he is not
>       penalised. Similarly, if a son steals from his father but before the
>       verdict is issued the father dies, the son is not punished, as stolen
>       goods now comprise his inheritance.
> 11. If the use of the stolen things is Harām (e.g. wine or pork), there is no penal action against the robber.
> 12. If the thief claims that he had not taken a particular thing with the intention of stealing it, and the judge considers otherwise, there
>       shall be no punishment for it.
> 13. The object should have been stolen from a place where the owner’s permission is required to enter. If a theft takes place in a public
>       mosque or public bath, the thief does not have his hand amputed.
> 14. The thing should have been stolen from a secure place.
> 15. The thief must himself take away the stolen goods from their proper place. If one takes out the thing from its safe place and
>       another one takes it away, neither of the two can be punished for
>       theft. If a thief removes the stolen object and loads it on his
>       animal, or gives it to an insane man or a minor child for taking it
>       away, he is penalised. This is because the animal, the insane person
>       and the child are mere carriers of the goods.
> 16. Severing of the hand is a punishment for theft. Theft implies that someone takes away something without the knowledge of others who later
>       realize that the thing is missing. Hence if a person forcibly loots
>       some goods from its owner, he is not punished for theft.
> 17. If before a theft can be proved, the thief goes to the judge and repents and promises not to steal in future he is saved from the
>       punishment.
> 18. For a theft to be proved, two just witnesses should have seen the thief stealing.
> 19. If the owner takes back his goods or allows the thief to keep them before the matter is reported to the Qazi and does not press for a
>       penalty, the thief is not punished.

Comment: Please don't mix your political views with Islam.

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin please elaborate your comment. if that is too long then write it as answer. if you think above answer is not correct.

Comment: @Zia just read the edit history!